# How to cleanup controller and views when a tab closes

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

In my application I have a main controller driving a series of tab opening. Each new Tab created a new controller is created driving the view represented by the tab. Actually there is one more view connected to the same controller, but it should not matter in my opinion. Well, tabs are closable, and when a tab closes I want to destroy the controller instance too. How can I reasch that controller? Storing it somewhere in the main controller violates the statement that a controller should not have a state, storing a reference of it in the view would make not so much sense since we can have more view related to a controller. So how mantain a proper control/ views association map?

Comment: Ext controllers are not really disposable. The Deft library has a concept of [`ViewController`](https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS/wiki/ViewController) that may be more appropriate in your case. One instance is created for each view instance, and automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Well just answering my own question to clarify. 
Since controller must be stateless, a single instance obtained by Application.getController('controllername') is enough to control *all* tabs, so there is not really a reason to cleanup the controller. My fault was using Ext.create() to create the controllers, that is basically wrong in my case, and probably always.